# Chunked response handling with spray example

Tags: http, scala, spray

Documentation [states](http://spray.io/documentation/spray-can/http-client/#chunked-responses) that spray is able to handle chunked responses but I can't find any example to start with. There is my naive implementation:

```
object Main extends App {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  import system.dispatcher
  val log = Logging(system, getClass)
  val ioBridge = IOExtension(system).ioBridge()
  val httpClient = system.actorOf(Props(new HttpClient(ioBridge)))

  val conduit = system.actorOf(
    props = Props(new HttpConduit(httpClient, "localhost", 3000)),
    name = "http-conduit"
  )

  val pipeline = HttpConduit.sendReceive(conduit)
  val response = pipeline(
    HttpRequest(
      method = GET,
      uri = "/output.cgi.xml"
    )
  )

  response onComplete {
    case Success(a) =>
      log.info("Success: " + a)
      system.shutdown()

    case Failure(error) =>
      log.error(error, "Failure")
      system.shutdown()
  }

}
```

I've set `response-chunk-aggregation-limit = 0`, nothing still happens.

Can you provide me with example of reading chunked response?

**Update**

I've rewritten my code as following:

```
object Main extends App {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  import system.dispatcher
  val log = Logging(system, getClass)
  val ioBridge = IOExtension(system).ioBridge()
  val httpClient = system.actorOf(Props(new HttpClient(ioBridge)))

  actor(new Act {
    httpClient ! Connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 3000))

    become {
      case Connected(_) =>
        log.info("connected")
        sender ! HttpRequest(GET, "/output.cgi.xml")
      case Closed(handle, reason) =>
        log.info("closed: " + reason)
        system.shutdown()
      case ChunkedResponseStart(res) =>
        log.info("start: " + res)
      case MessageChunk(body, ext) =>
        log.info("chunk: " + body)
      case ChunkedMessageEnd(ext, trailer) =>
        log.info("end: " + ext)
      case m =>
        log.info("received unknown message " + m)
        system.shutdown()
    }
  })

}
```

And now I'm receiving `closed: ProtocolError(Aggregated response entity greater than configured limit of 1048576 bytes)` just after connection is established.

My application.conf

```
spray.can {
  client {
    response-chunk-aggregation-limit = 0
  }
}
```

Comment: WDYM with "nothing still happens"? Are you saying you never get a result to the query?

Comment: Which version of spray do you use?

Comment: I'm using 1.1-M7. I mean I don't know how to handle response in a chunked way. Currently `onComplete` receives aggregated response.

Answer (score 9):

As you have noticed, HttpConduit only works on aggregated responses. You have to fall down to the spray-can layer do handle single chunks.

Unfortunately, we currently have no example showing how you would do this. Roughly, it works like this (in M7):

1. Set `response-chunk-aggregation-limit = 0`
2. Send `Connect` to httpClient actor and wait for `Connected`
3. Send `HttpRequest` to the sender of the `Connected` message
4. Handle chunked request messages `ChunkedResponseStart`, `MessageChunk`, and `ChunkedResponseEnd`.

For more info see http://spray.io/documentation/spray-can/http-client/#chunked-responses

In contrast to using `HttpConduit`, this means you have to manage your connections yourself (if that's why you were using HttpConduit). In recent nightlies it got easier, because the new `HttpClient` automatically supports connection pools, etc. If you need that you can also get more info at the mailing list.

Comment: Does it mean that my client will receive every big enough response as chunks, or some special server-side support is needed?

Comment: You currently get chunks only if the server sends chunks. I added a ticket to support a chunk API even if the actual response isn't chunked over the wire: https://github.com/spray/spray/issues/281